# Изменение надписи по нажатию на кнопкe

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать так, чтобы щелчок по второй кнопке удалял надпись привет, и отображал новую другого цвета, например "Пока !"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и в чем вопрос?:

Comment: Ну и как это сделать

Comment: Что то сами пробовали? Документацию читали?

Comment: Вы же смогли сделать изменение видимости надписи. Сделайте еще один шаг - посмотрите какие еще свойства у надписи вы можете менять так же, как сейчас меняете видимость.